# Variable declaration inside 'if' statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

My question is potentially embarrassing. I'd consult google if I knew what question to ask specifically, but alas, I'm a code newbie and as such am not familiar with the jargon...

I'm following a written tutorial @https://javascript.info. I'm on the lesson about conditional operators and if statements, having trouble wrapping my head around the behaviour of one of the tasks (http://javascript.info/ifelse#tasks), specifically task #4. "Check the login".

Here's the code:

```js
let userLogin = prompt("Who's there?", "");

if (userLogin == 'Admin') {

  let pass = prompt("Password?", ""); // *******    

  if (pass == 'TheMaster') {
    alert('Welcome!');
  } else if (!pass) {
    alert("Canceled.");
  } else {
    alert('I do not know you');
  }

} else if (!userLogin) {
  alert("Canceled");
} else {
  alert("I don't know you")
}
```

My question revolves around the (****) line. The code doesn't work properly if that line isn't nested in the 'if', which threw me way off ( had it as a "global" variable to begin with, had to check the solution because I couldnt find the bug ).

I ask of you, please, clarify why that is so. :(

**edit** 
I didn't realise I was being unspecific. I'm completely new to the forum, won't happen again.

The code doesn't work, meaning writing 'Admin' into the first prompt isn't necessary to proceed to the 'pass' prompt. This behaviour only happens when I don't nest the "pass" declaration inside 'if'. I *think* I have found my answer, but wanted to edit as to not further agitate the community. :P

```
let userLogin = prompt("Who's there?", "");
let pass = prompt("Password?", ""); // ******* 

if (userLogin == 'Admin') {


  if (pass == 'TheMaster') {
    alert('Welcome!');
  } else if (!pass) {
    alert("Canceled.");
  } else {
    alert('I do not know you');
  }

} else if (!userLogin) {
  alert("Canceled");
} else {
  alert("I don't know you")
}
```

This is what I mean - hope this clarifies! Sorry again.

Comment: You are doing two things in that line: `prompt` asks the user for his password and then the value is assigned to the variable `pass`. If you want to declare this variable globally you need to split the assignment from the variable declaration.

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: The code works fine for me if I move that line up before the `if()`.

Comment: Sorry lads, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that you had the pass either in a separate nested scope, or declared after it was being used. `let` declarations are not `hoisted` like `var` declarations. So they must be accessed from the same scope, or a more nested scope of that scope, AFTER their declaration.

```js
let userLogin = prompt("Who's there?", "");
let pass = prompt("Password?", ""); // *******    
if (userLogin == 'Admin') {

    

    if (pass == 'TheMaster') {
        alert('Welcome!');
    } else if (!pass) {
        alert("Canceled.");
    } else {
        alert('I do not know you');
    }

} else if (!userLogin) {
    alert("Canceled");
} else {
    alert("I don't know you")
}
```

a link to definition of hoisting if you're curious : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

PS - I hope this is just a toy problem... but incase it isn't *please* do not use this to perform actual authentication. Anything which is in the Javascript of a page is visible to all and your username and password will *NOT* be secure.

Comment: `"I don't know you"`, priceless!

Comment: It's simply a task on a tutorial website - fret not! Thanks for the link. I tried with both let and var with the same result, though. But again, I'm a complete newb and probably did something messed up and illogical.

Comment: @SorenNissen Put `let pass = prompt("Password?", "");` back into the `if` statement and then try to print it out after the last `else`. Then try the same, but replace `let` with `var`.

Comment: @Jimenenex - That's interesting. I suppose it's for debugging purposes for beginners? Thanks - I'll definitely keep that in mind

Comment: @SorenNissen It's a demonstration on one of the differences between `let` and `var` and why their placement is important in terms of their scope and how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I found is that if you remove the line (***) from the if block  the script will ask the user for the **userLogin** and the **pass**, and then do the checking. If you do not, the script will ask for the **userLogin** and if this is not correct, you will not waste time asking for the **pass**. As the others say, it would be better to explain what problem you have exactly.